# Pre-set value in adaptive card input number

Tags: adaptive-cards

How to set a value to an `Input.Number` using data context?

None of these Adaptive cards work:

```
{
      "type": "Input.Number",
      "placeholder": "id",
      "id": "MyId",
      "value": "$root.MyId"
}

{..., "value": $root.MyId }

{..., "value": "${$root.MyId}" }

{..., "$data": "${$root}" }

{..., "$data": "${$root.MyId}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's one example thats working:
https://github.com/DeeJayTC/AdaptiveCardsPeopleApp/blob/master/AdaptiveCardsVuePeople/src/assets/personCreate.json

You just had your syntax slightly off.

This should work:

```json
{
   "label": "Job Title",
   "type": "Input.Text",
   "placeholder": "Persons's Job Title",
   "value": "${$root.jobTitle}",
   "id": "job"
}
```

Comment: Input.text works just fine. It is input.number i am talking about